# Why don't these elements render to PDF with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have working code that generates a report from my server, however when Puppeteer PDF's the report it is leaving out some elements, and I'm not sure why.

Here is how the output should look:

[image: Here is how the output should look]

But this is what I end up with (don't worry about the missing percentages, it's not relevant):

[image]

The code for these elements are:

```
<div>
  <i class="bx bxs-checkbox me-2 font-22 text-info"></i>
</div>
```

All of the classes and CSS seems to be loading correctly, but I just can't get them to render to the PDF...

```
var printPDF = async function printPDF(agency, agencyAdmin, agencyTitle, callback) {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox', 
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox', 
            '--allow-file-access-from-files',
            '--start-maximized'
            ],
        defaultViewport: null,
        devtools:true
    });


    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.setViewport({
          width: 1120,
          height: 1025,
          deviceScaleFactor: 1,
          hasTouch: false,
          isLandscape: false
    });
    
    // console log anything from the page.
    page.on('console', async msg => {
          const args = msg.args();
          const vals = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            vals.push(await args[i].jsonValue());
          }
          console.log(vals.map(v => typeof v === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(v, null, 2) : v).join('\t'));
    });
    
    await page.goto(`file://${__dirname}/reporting/index.html?agency=${agency}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0 });
        
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000)
    
    const pdf = await page.pdf({ 
      width: '11.7in',
      height: '16.54in',
      scale: 1,
      margin: {
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0
      },
      printBackground: true
    });
    
    await browser.close();
  
        //Email the report
            const message = {
                from: 'me',
                to: agencyAdmin,
                subject: 'Monthyy Report',
                text: `[Automatically Generated for ${agencyTitle}]\n\n\nHello, please find attached your monthly usage report.`,
                attachments: [
                  {
                      filename: `Monthly_Usage_Report_${agencyTitle}.pdf`,
                      content: pdf 
                  }
                ]
            }; 
                    
            mailtransport.sendMail(message, function(err, info) {
                        
                if (err) {
                  console.log('[Outgoing Email] ', err)
                } else {
                  console.log('[Outgoing Email] Sent OK: ', info.accepted);
                }
            });
            
    callback()
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any of those switches in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow, the report prints to PDF in portrait orientation

Comment: I tried to disable the `printBackground` option which resulted in the colors being removed from most of the bootstrap elements. Not sure which other flag @KJ is referring to

Comment: @TangoMike did you finally get somewhere with that issue?

Comment: No, I didn't. Are you seeing the same?